# Windowactivate three windows with same name

Tags: windows, automation, windows-10, autohotkey

In Pulover's Macro creator I'd like to use the command *windowactivate* to activate 3 windows sequentially. They share the same name.

I tried to create a loop but it didn't work as expected.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This AutoHotkey script will activate multiple windows, with the same name, sequentially.
In case that helps.

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
WinGet, vWinList, List, Untitled - Notepad
Loop, %vWinList%
{
hWnd := vWinList%A_Index%
WinActivate, ahk_id %hWnd%
Sleep 3000
}
Return
```